# Display images present in $scope object

Tags: angularjs

I have markup like this. In my `img` `ng-init` I am passing an image value coming from the `ng-repeat`. Currently two values are passed which are then used to fetch data from an API.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">

    <div class="well well-sm">{{x.room_type}}<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#room_detail{{$index}}" class="pull-right">Room Details</a>
    </div>
    <h5 class="pull-right">{{x.rack_price}}<br>Per room per night</h5>
    <img  ng-src="{{room_image}}" ng-init=fetchImage(x.image)>

</div>
```

Here's my GET method inside the `fetchImage` function

```
$scope.fetchImage = function(value){
            $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '&image_id=' + value
        }).then(function (response) {
                var imgdata = response.data;
                var imgdata1 = imgdata.data.image_name;
                $scope.room_image = "/" + imgdata1;

                console.info($scope.room_image);
            });
        };
```

My console shows me two image `URLS`. Like

```
https://uploads/165753081311.08.10-c_ft_p_2_582_379.jpg 
https://uploads/950286957i-ma-ss-1920-800x450.jpg
```

But in my view where I have used `img ng-src={{room_image}}` I can only see the image from the second URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because second value overwrites first one. You should have `x.room_image` there. Also, notice that I made `fetchImage(x)` change. Like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">

    <div class="well well-sm">{{x.room_type}}<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#room_detail{{$index}}" class="pull-right">Room Details</a>
    </div>
    <h5 class="pull-right">{{x.rack_price}}<br>Per room per night</h5>
    <img  ng-src="{{x.room_image}}" ng-init=fetchImage(x)>

</div>
```

So, `fetchImage` function would look like this:

```
$scope.fetchImage = function(x){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '&image_id=' + x.image
    }).then(function (response) {
        var imgdata = response.data;
        var imgdata1 = imgdata.data.image_name;
        x.room_image = "/" + imgdata1;
        console.info(x.room_image);
    });
};
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @SLASH haha! glad I could help :)